# Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out while accessing gcp storage through Spring Boot Java Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have configured the proxy and when I run the application locally it is working fine but when I ran it on the server it is giving me the mentioned error
Below is how I defined my proxy

```
@Bean
    public Storage storage() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(keys)));       
        NetHttpTransport.Builder builder = new NetHttpTransport.Builder();
        builder.setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress(host,port)));
        NetHttpTransport httpTransport = builder.build();
        HttpTransportFactory hf = new HttpTransportFactory() {
            @Override
            public HttpTransport create() {
                return httpTransport;
            }
        };

        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
       .setTransportOptions(HttpTransportOptions.newBuilder().setHttpTransportFactory(hf).build())
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build().getService();

        return storage;
    }
```

I'm using base64 encrypted Json Key file.
Am I missing something here while configuring the proxy if yes then why it is working on my local machine?

I tried debugging it but all I got is the request getting printed again and again

```
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.27.0 (gzip)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 811

curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.27.0 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' << $$$
```

And getting socket timed out